# Non-isomorphic abelian groups of order $3^2\times 5^2\times 7^2$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups

I just want to make sure that my understanding of the following problem is correct:

Suppose we want to find how many non-isomorphic abelian groups there are of order $3^2\times 5^2\times 7^2$.

Then, since 3,5, and 7 are all prime, we know that the number of non-isomorphic abelian groups of this order will be $2^3=8$, since the number of partitions of 2 is just 2.

Further, if we consider another example, say $3^2\times 5^2\times 7^5$, then we know that there will be (2)(2)(7)=28 non-isomorphic abelian groups of this order because there are 7 partitions of 5. This is done via the Fundamental Theorem for Fin. Gen. Abelian groups.

Is this all correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is correct.  Partitions are the key to counting finite abelian groups.

Comment: Do you mind explaining this a bit further? Thanks!

Comment: Well by the structure theorem they are products of cyclic groups of prime power order, say.  Then just look at partitions of the exponents, as the OP did above. @NoelLundström

Comment: For instance, start really small.  When $n=4=2^2$, look at partitions of the exponent $2$.  There are $2$.  $2+0$ and $1+1$.  Thus we get the corresponding products of cyclic groups $\Bbb Z_4$ and $\Bbb Z_2×\Bbb Z_2$. @NoelLundström

Comment: Ah, that's neat.